# CoreData: Accessing one-to-one relationship attribute

Tags: core-data, attributes, entity

Two entities:

- **Notification**
- **User**

`Notification` has a one-to-one `relationship` with User called "`senderUser`". In NSManagedObject file for `Notification`, `senderUser` looks like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *senderUser;
```

Sender user has an NSString property called `username`

What's the correct syntax to access the property?  I have tried the following and I'm getting an error:

```
Notification *managedObject = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *senderUN = [managedObject valueForKey:@"senderUser.username"];
```

Error:

```
 `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Notification 0xbc4ad80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Notification is not key value coding-compliant for the key "senderUser.username"`.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it almost right:

```
NSString *senderUN = [managedObject valueForKeyPath:@"senderUser.username"];
```

because "senderUser.username" is not a single key, but a key path with two
components.

Comment: Martin to the rescue once again!  Thanks.

Comment: Martin:  Do you have time to help me with this Core Data question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508538/delete-an-object-from-one-to-many-relationship     Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this Martin! I was really struggling to understand why I couldn't access my attributes!