# Delete an object from one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

Two Entities:

- `Notification`
- `User`

`User` has an attribute called `username`

There is one-to-many `relationship` between `User` <<---> `Notification` called "users"

There is a `Notification` object (ObjectA) saved that has (2) `User`Objects saved in the "users" relationship.  I would like to update ObjectA by deleting one of the `User` object in "users" relationship.

`User` entity has an attribute called "username".

There are (2) `User'`s with username "UserA" & "UserB" as objects in the "users" relationship, how would I delete "UserA"?

Here is what I came up with and it's not working:

```
NSFetchRequest *notificationRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Notification"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notification_id == %@", [selectedManagedObject valueForKey:@"notification_id"]];
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:notificationRequest onSuccess:^(NSArray *results) 
{
   //Since I'm fetching based on objectID, there should always be one Object.
    Notification *notificationObject = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *usersArray = [NSArray alloc]init];

             //I don't think the code below is correct?  

    usersArray =  [notificationObject valueForKey:@"users"];

    for (User *user in userArray)
    {
        if (user.username == @"UserA")
        {
             [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:user];
             [self.managedObjectContext saveOnSuccess:^{
         } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
          }];

     } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {

     }];
```

**EDIT**

[image]

What's the best way to delete "UserA" object from the relationship?

Comment: In what way is this not working?

Comment: Instead of just deleting the UserA object from the users relationship, it is deleting the entire Notification object.

Answer (score 1):

If deleting a "User" object also deletes the related "Notification" object,
then you probably have set the "Delete Rule" for the relationship from "User" to "Notification" to "Cascade". You should set it to "Nullify" instead.

Note also that the string comparison

```
if (user.username == @"UserA")
```

is wrong, it should be

```
if ([user.username isEqualToString:@"UserA")
```

That does however not explain why the "Notification" object is deleted.

Comment: Thanks.  I verified and the "Delete Rule" is set for "Nullify".  Please see the Edit.

Comment: Also. Should I have an inverse relationship?

Comment: @user1107173: There is an error in your code (see updated answer). But that does not explain why the Notification object is deleted. - And yes, you should always define the inverse relationship.

Comment: @user1107173: Your screenshot shows the relationship from Notification to User. My answer was about the relationship from User to Notification!

Comment: You are right.  Notification has a relationship with Users, called users.  A notification object can have multiple Users in the users relationship, at least that's what I understand.

Comment: @user1107173: That is correct. Do you have a inverse relationship from User to Notification?

Comment: no I do not.  I will set it up and try again.  I should be in front of my computer in an hour.

Comment: @user1107173: OK, good luck. (But even without the inverse relationship, I cannot see from your code why deleting a User should delete the complete Notification.)